# corpus2dense requires two arguments, but tutorial example only uses one

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

I posted this issue on github (https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/274)

However, I need help with how to actually use the compatibility with numpy that gensim has.

I tried passing in None, `len(corpus)`, and 0-2 all failing.

The following is the corpus:

```
[(0, 1.0), (1, 1.0), (2, 1.0)]
[(0, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0), (6, 1.0), (7, 1.0)]
[(2, 1.0), (5, 1.0), (7, 1.0), (8, 1.0)]
[(1, 1.0), (5, 2.0), (8, 1.0)]
[(3, 1.0), (6, 1.0), (7, 1.0)]
[(9, 1.0)]
[(9, 1.0), (10, 1.0)]
[(9, 1.0), (10, 1.0), (11, 1.0)]
[(4, 1.0), (10, 1.0), (11, 1.0)]
```

This is the code which doesn't work in my iPython notebook:

```
from gensim import matutils
corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('/tmp/corpus.mm')
import numpy
numpy_matrix = matutils.corpus2dense(corpus)
```

Which throws IndexErrors

Comment: I don't know this library, but if "term" of a matrix means "entry", since each tuple is 2 entries, then you wouldn't want `len(corpus)` but `2*len(corpus)`. I could be way off, but I don't think should be too hard to check. Sorry, if this doesn't work though.

Comment: That is correct @Bair, thank you. Could you answer this with more that explains why I need to do `2*len(corpus)` so I can mark it right?

Comment: Yep. Glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, it should be `2*len(corpus)` instead of `len(corpus)`.